# What is the NgXS state flow here?

Tags: angular, state, ngxs

I am trying to understand the state flow of `NgXS` here in an `Angular 12` application.

There is the service, which I believe performs the actual retrieval of configuration from the API:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUserConfig = () => this.http.get<UserConfig>(`${env.api.url}/user/config`);

}
```

Then there is the state class, which first provides selecting items from state and secondly populating the state by calling the service (above):

```js
@State<UsrStateModel>({
    name: 'appState',
    defaults: {
        usr: null,
        ...
    }
})
@Injectable()
export class UsrState implements NgxsOnInit, NgxsAfterBootstrap {
    constructor(
        private userService: UserService
    ) { }

@Selector()
static userConfig(state: UserStateModel): UserConfig | null {
    return state.userData.userConfig;
}

@Action(GetUserConfig)
getUserConfig(ctx: StateContext<UsrStateModel>) {
    return this.userService.getUserConfig().pipe(tap(
        data => {
            ctx.setState(patch({ userData: patch({ userConfig: data }) }));
        }
    ));
}
```

Then there is the consuming component of the state:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  destroy$ = new Subject();
  userConfig: UserConfig;

  populateUserConfig = () => {
    this.userConfig$.pipe(filter(a => a != null), distinctUntilChanged(), takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(data => {
      this.userConfig = data;
    });
  }
}
```

My question is, will the data assigned to `this.userConfig` in `populateUserConfig` be completely populated, or will it's content only be fully available later?

My current understanding is that observables provide a stream of values but if their values are written to a non-observable variable that variable (should be) accessible as if is has finished being assigned a complete value. Is this correct?

Comment: the data retrieved from the `userConfig$` observable will be available when the async call from the api is fulfilled, your variable `userConfig` value will be `undefined` until then. That variable is accessible regardless of the observable call and its value may be `undefined` or the api's response depending on when do your try to use its value. Also it will only save the last value returned by the observable as it's being overwritten every time. I'm not sure if this answer your question as I'm not sure of what you ask, please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly clear on your use case for wrapping the observable logic in a named function `populateUserConfig`... possibly you are wanting to control when you actually create the subscription etc?

The named function `populateUserConfig` will not hold data / be populated as it is just a function that executes your subscription.

- `this.populateUserConfig()` simply executes the subscription to the
  observable `this.userConfig$` which in turn hydrates
  `this.userConfig` with any data emitted from that observable stream.

looking at the observable itself:

```
this.userConfig$.pipe(filter(a => a != null), distinctUntilChanged(), takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(data => {
      this.userConfig = data;
    });
```

This will subscribe to the observable `this.userConfig$` and filter out any nulls via `filter(a => a != null)`, and any non-distinct values via `distinctUntilChanged()`, and will continue to emit new data via `takeUntil(this.destroy$))` until `this.destroy$`emits.

- This subscription will continually update `this.userConfig` with non
  null distinct values until told to destroy ensuring your variable `this.userConfig` always has the latest emit from the observable stream.

Regarding your question of `will the data assigned to this.userConfig in populateUserConfig be completely populated, or will it's content only be fully available later?`

- That truly depends on when you invoke `populateUserConfig()` to
  create the subscription and start listening for data from the `this.userConfig$` observable.
- If invoked in a class constructor, for example, it would probably hydrate `this.userConfig` with data as soon as it becomes available etc